# Setting color of ListView items

Tags: android

I'm trying to individually set the color of certain ListView items like phone number and email address to blue, so that user knows they're clickable.  Here's a snippet but implementing this doesn't work well at all, list items will randomly change colors when you scroll the list.

```
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    //...add data to list

    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.simple_list_item_2_custom, new String[] { LABEL, VALUE },
        new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 })
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            String label = data.get(position).get(LABEL);

            if (label.equals("Email Address"))
            {
                ((TextView)view.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            return view;
        }
    };
```

And here's the LinearLayout that defines a list item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: randomly, what do you mean?

Comment: like when you scroll up or down and list items appear and disappear from the visible area, they will (seemingly) randomly be either blue or the default color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the else of "if (label.equals("Email Address"))"

You have to place another text color when it is not an email address, like this:
((TextView)view.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

The reason is cause Android adapter reuses the old line which is no long being displayed, in this case the one you already defined to blue.

Comment: I was looking for the full explanation on the docs, but I can't remember where it is.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  This behavior is very weird to me, I'll look for the docs on it myself.