# How to change the background image of a Listview button according to the position?

Tags: android, listview

My listview contains more than 200 items. In every row of the listview, there is a Button. I want to change the Button background according to the position.Well I am able to change it too but the problem is after scrolling the listview, the images are assigned to some other button.If I am changing the button text, everything is fine but if changing the button background, this weird problem comes.

Below is what I have tried so far,

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public MyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        Button button=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;

        if (position==2 || position==3) {
           button.setText("Invited");
           } 
         else if (position==5 || position==8) {
         button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graph);
          }
       else {
       text.setText("Invite");
       }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Each of these answers looks correct, so maybe you could mark one as accepted? This is a common problem, but really easy to stumble over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the odd-even number logic in getview method.............

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
if(convertView==null)
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

if (position % 2 == 0) {
   button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_1);
 }else {
   button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_2);
 }

return vi;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple problem my friend, this is caused cause Android Adapter implementation re-uses the components once it get off the screen, thats so it take a button which background already had been changed, so you have to set in your logic to make it back to the default background.
This is a common error by missing full doc reads.
Here is a similar problem: [Setting color of ListView items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456673/setting-color-of-listview-items/17456736#17456736)

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` recycles the views, what that mean is you have to reset the states in `getView()` method so do it like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    Button button=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
    button.setBackgroundResource(0); // reset the color again
    if (position==2 || position==3) {
       button.setText("Invited");
     } else if (position==5 || position==8) {
       button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graph);
     } else {
       text.setText("Invite");
     }

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will try it and will update you soon.